# AppDynamics with Azure Functions

Tags: azure, azure-functions, appdynamics

Has anybody solved to monitor Azure functions using AppDynamics ? I don't see any option to add a AppDynamics extension to the Azure functions app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could install the AppDynamics extension use Azure portal or Kudu tool(https://functionAppname.scm.azurewebsites.net/).

**Azure Portal:**

[image]

**Kudu UI**

[image]

**After installation**

[image]

Comment: Seems I got my function to connect, but it doesn't send data. Did you have to do anything else?